# AURemoteIO - Accept incoming VOIP call in the background using Twilio on iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios5, core-audio, twilio

In our system, we have a Rails server initiating a conference call to an iphone device, and a landline. When our iphone app receives the incoming call while the app is in the background, we see a series of error messages regarding a failed initialization of AURemoteIO. The errors are as follows:

```
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16>)
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16>)
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  32000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  32000 Hz, Int16>)
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16>)
<0x4336000> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -12985 (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,   8000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,   8000 Hz, Int16>)
```

From what we can tell in the log messages, this occurs at some point after or during the didReceiveIncomingConnection callback. Here is the code for that function:

```
-(void)device:(TCDevice*)device didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection*)connection{
    if ( _connection ){
        [self disconnect];
    }
    _connection = [connection retain];
    [_connection accept];
}
```

Unfortunately, we never reach the `connectionDidConnect` function. This does work properly, however, in the foreground. Sadly, this is a necessary requirement of the application (to run in the background).

We have **UIBackgroundMode** set to **location**, **VOIP**, and **audio**.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open the audio device while the application is in the background.

in the [callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/incoming-connections):

```
-(void)device:(TCDevice*)device didReceiveIncomingConnection:(TCConnection*)connection
```

call you should present a UILocalNotification to the user telling them there is an incoming call, then once the user "opens" the notification (thus bringing the application to the foreground) you should THEN call:

```
[_connection accept];
```

Comment: Ah ha, gotcha. This is as we suspected. Thank you very much for your help!